# Add Piwik Tracking code to page

Tags: html

I use piwik analytics to track the visitors to my website. I recently created a blog on WordPress and wanted to added the same tracking code that I use on the plain HTML webpage. How can I added the tracking script in the php in order to track my blog visitors?

thanks!

Comment: [This plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-analytics-tracking/) helps to include tracking-codes (not only for Piwik, but also Google Analytics etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the tracking code to one of your theme files, most likely `footer.php`.

The easiest way to do this is to go to your admin panel and go to Appearance > Editor, and on the right side, find the entry for Footer (footer.php), and then insert the code right before the closing `</body>` tag. Update the file by clicking the button below the text box, and you should be good!

Comment: Thank you, I was adding it to my templates but the footer worked much better! (I'd give you an upvote but alas not enough rep!)

Comment: No problem, glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You'll find Step by step instruction on how to install Piwik on [the Wordpress site here](http://wponcpanel.com/analytics/piwik-installation-through-softaculous/).

Comment: +1, but an answer should be more than a link. Please read a bit in the FAQ to get a better feeling how this site works. Thanks.

Comment: The external website is about installing Piwik via Cpanel ... so most of the article is not related to the original question. @wpboss ... its ok to answer a question and reference an article on your own website, but don't over do the linkbaiting / SEO

Comment: Link returns “Server not found” – that's why it should be more than a link.